# Add RUN_ID as part of airflow logs

Tags: python-3.x, logging, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-webserver

I have been reading a lot about logging in to Airflow and experimenting a lot but could not achieve what I am looking for. I want to customize the logging for Airflow. I have a lot of DAGs. Each DAG has multiple tasks. EAch DAG has multiple tasks corresponding to one alert_name. DAG is running hourly and pushing logs to S3. If something goes wrong and debugging is required it is very tough to look for logs in S3. I want to customize the logs to search the log lines by RUN_ID and alert_name.

I have the following piece of code.

```
from airflow import DAG  # noqa
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import y

import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'SRE',
    'execution_timeout': timedelta(minutes=150)
}


dag = DAG(
    dag_id = 'new_dag',
    default_args = default_args,
    start_date = datetime(year=2021, month=11, day=22),
    schedule_interval = timedelta(days=1),
    catchup = False,
    max_active_runs = 3,
)

def implement_alert_logic(alert_name):
    log.info(f'In the implementation for {alert_name}')
    pass

def myfunc(**wargs):
    for alert in ['alert_1', 'alert_2', 'alert_3']:
        log.info(f'Executing logic for {alert}')
        implement_alert_logic(alert)



t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='testing_this',
    python_callable = myfunc,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='testing_this2',
    python_callable = myfunc,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

t1 >> t2
```

It prints something like

```
[2022-06-13, 08:16:54 UTC] {myenv.py:32} INFO - Executing logic for alert_1
[2022-06-13, 08:16:54 UTC] {myenv.py:27} INFO - In the implementation for alert_1
[2022-06-13, 08:16:54 UTC] {myenv.py:32} INFO - Executing logic for alert_2
[2022-06-13, 08:16:54 UTC] {myenv.py:27} INFO - In the implementation for alert_2
[2022-06-13, 08:16:54 UTC] {myenv.py:32} INFO - Executing logic for alert_3
[2022-06-13, 08:16:54 UTC] {myenv.py:27} INFO - In the implementation for alert_3
```

Actual code is much more complex and sophisticated than this. That's why I need faster and more customized debugging logs.

What I am trying to achieve is to customize the log formatter and add RUN_ID and alert_name as part of the log_message

Logs should be something like this:

```
[2022-06-13, 08:16:54 UTC] [manual__2022-06-13T08:16:54.103265+00:00] {myenv.py:32} INFO - Executing logic for alert_1
[2022-06-13, 08:16:54 UTC] [manual__2022-06-13T08:16:54.103265+00:00] [alert1]{myenv.py:32} INFO - In the implementation for alert_1
```

Answer (score 3):

So i finally managed this:

if you are using the kubernetes executor combined with a helm chart installation it goes as follows:

in the helm values add:

```
config:
  logging:
    # default logging for API, scheduler and triggerer
    log_format: '{"level": "%%(levelname)s", "ts": "%%(asctime)s", "caller": "%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d", "msg": "%%(message)s"}'
    logging_config_class: log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG


extraEnv: |
  - name: TRACE_ID
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: metadata.labels['run_id']
```

We need to add a default logging format. This is needed for the health check logs. Then we overwrite the logging_config_class that we later will inject into the image.

Because airflow does not inject the run_id (i called it trace_id) in the worker pods you will need to read it from the logs. The env key in helm has some broken validation on it but the extraEnv is using a string template without validation and can be used to extract the run_id from the label and inject is as environment variable.

Then create a log_config.py file:

```py
import os
from copy import deepcopy

from airflow.config_templates.airflow_local_settings import (
    DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG,
)

LOGGING_CONFIG = deepcopy(DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG)

for formatter in LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"]:
    run_id = os.environ.get("TRACE_ID", "")
    if run_id and run_id != "None":
        LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"][formatter]["format"] = (
            '{"level": "%(levelname)s", "ts": "%(asctime)s", "caller":'
            ' "%(filename)s:%(lineno)d", "msg": "%(message)s", "trace_id":'
            f' "{run_id}"}}'
        )
    else:
        LOGGING_CONFIG["formatters"][formatter]["format"] = (
            '{"level": "%(levelname)s", "ts": "%(asctime)s", "caller":'
            ' "%(filename)s:%(lineno)d", "msg": "%(message)s"}'
        )
```

here is want to check for a trace_id as environment variable. It will not exist on some of the pods and will be set to None if kubernetes cannot find it.

So basically we append the current layout with an injected trace_id.

Now we need to inject the config in our airflow pod with docker:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 apache/airflow
COPY ./config/log_config.py /opt/airflow/config/log_config.py
```

Not happy how hacky this is but here you go...

Answer (score 0):

You are already sending the context to the callable, just make use of it

```
def myfunc(**wargs):
    for alert in ['alert_1', 'alert_2', 'alert_3']:
        log.info(f"[{wargs['run_id']}] [{alert}] Executing logic for {alert}")
        implement_alert_logic(alert)
```

Then just send the whole context or just the run_id also to `implement_alert_logic` function.

Comment: Your codes cannot generate the expected outcome as mentioned in the question, where **customize the log formatter** is not achieved.  **RUN_ID and alert_name as part of the log_message** is not achieved as you logged the `RUN_ID` in a new line of log instead of the *part of the log_message* as shown in the expected outcome codes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem with this approach, if I have 100 log lines in the implementation of Python Operator callable, I will have to add `kwargs['run-id']` in every log message.

I want to include the RUN_ID and alert_name in log format itself.